# GAE: how to properly handle google shutting down a backend instance?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, module, backend

Is there a good tutorial for how to properly write a backend/module for GAE to handle shutdowns?

This is the error I am getting:

```
2014-04-09 12:15:44.726 Process terminated because the backend took too long to shutdown.
```

I have a process that will take a few hours, and I know that I'll have to basically save the state into the memcache, and then restart it.

Are there tutorials for:
1) how to handle a shutdown request
2) how to save to memcache
3) how to restart a module

1) and 2) seem straightforward... restarting a module is something I'm unsure about. My module starts as a cron job, but is there a way to use a shutdown request to trigger another instance of my module to start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have big jobs operating on a large amount of data, then you might look into [map reduce](https://code.google.com/p/appengine-mapreduce/).

Anyhow, you should break your large job down to smaller idempotent tasks. Idempotent (without side effects) basically means you can rerun a task getting the same results.

Once you have smaller tasks you can choose to schedule them via Task Queue or use a map reduce framework.

Things to note:

1. You are not guaranteed to get a shutdown callback. Our backend instances are restarted every day and our shutdown hooks do not get called.
2. Memcache is not reliable. Do not treat it as permanent storage.

Comment: Thank you for the response -- so I can easily parallelize my code... is the idea that I have a script that calls task queues individually to perform smaller tasks? Basically the script needs to download a file (~150mb zipped... 500mb unzipped) from a remote server and process each file in the archive (~40,000 files). Would I spin up 40,000 tasks to process each file?

Comment: Tasks running on frontend instances have a 10min limit (no limit on backend instances though). You should break down tasks to comfortably fit into this execution timeframe.

Comment: Just finished changing the script into using task queues -- made the job leaps and bounds easier. Thank you for the help, I really appreciate it.